# Python, How can I replace values depending on other values in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to replace values in a dataset with reasonable data.

There are NAN values in the column 'Age' which I want to replace under these conditions:

If the name of the Person has the string "Mrs" in it and:

> if Age value == Nan:
>
> > replace(Nan value with 40)

I am using this code:

```
c = dftrain[dftrain['Age'].isnull()]
a = c["Name"].str.contains("Mrs.")
```

c (boolean) = all rows with Nan for age

a = all rows with the string Mrs.

Please help me :) !!!

Comment: `dftrain.loc[dftrain['Age'].isnull() & df['Name'].str.contains('Mrs.'), 'Age'] = 40`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope below lines work for you...

## frame Input-

```
       Name  Age
0  Mrs XYZ   21
1  Mr Devid  NaN
2  Mrs OPQ   NAN

#I have taken through excel you can use your own way

import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df.loc[df['Name'].str.contains('Mrs.') & df['Age'].isnull(), 'Age'] = 40

print(df)

# Output Frame - 
       Name  Age
0  Mrs XYZ   21
1  Mr Devid  NaN
2  Mrs OPQ  40
```

Comment: But how can I replace  values lower than 1  instead of an NaN value? I tried this line but it does not work.                                                                              dftrain.loc[dftrain['Name'].str.contains('Master.') & dftrain[dftrain.Age<1], 'Age']=5

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas as Hietsh suggested above.

I would change only the condition format as specified below:

```html
import pandas as pds

data = pds.read_excel('as1.xlsx')
df = pds.DataFrame(data, columns=['Product', 'Title', 'Name', 'Age'])

df.loc[((df['Age'].isnull()) & (df['Title'] == ('Mrs.'))), 'Age'] = 40
```

As a good reference I suggest the [Pandas website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)